# Implement persistency in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to implement the concept of persistency into a simulink module.

It is associated with "faults" (overcurrent, overvoltage etc...) and the idea if *IF* a threshold is crossed for a period of time a FAULT is asserted for a period of time.

I was working on something like this and a triggered subsystem with regards to a comparator but it didn't seem to function as expected

[Accumulator in Simulink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770144/accumulator-in-simulink)

Comment: "FAULT is asserted for a period of time." <-- please precise what that means. Will fault return to zero at a fixed time after it was set to 1? ...a fixed time after the cause (overcurrent etc) returns to 0? What happens if the cause occurs again within this period?

Comment: It's not very clear, but sounds like you need a state machine, which is done in [Stateflow](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/stateflow/).

Comment: Sorry, I figured this one out. an Enabled subsystem with an accumulator - reset on disable with a final OR gate. It doesn't do the UP/DOWN for persistency but the UP part was the main concern